# Excahnge server Settings to Display only email address for the external users

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

What configuration setting in exchange server has to be changed so that **"Display Name"** should not be displayed and only **email address** to be displayed for endusers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge and tested in my exchange 2016 lab, it seems to be hard to achieve.